# How do I get a div to fill the height of its wrapper when it has a float on it?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to build a responsive design from the ground up and using jsfiddle to do some testing.  I have two outer columns with fixed widths and a central column that takes up the remaining width in between.  I cannot for the life of me get the outer columns to expand to fill the height of the wrapper they are in.  I think this may have something to do with how I got the middle div to take the central space (putting it after the right div in the order and then adding overflow:hidden).

I have tried clearing the floats with a div with clear:both on it and have also tried adding overflow:hidden to the wrapper.

The jsfiddle link is : http://jsfiddle.net/jleslie/ErAWn/1/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow JLeslie. Questions are expected to contain pieces of code in them. This not only helps other users understand what your problem is, but it makes easier to identify problems and make suggestions. Try adding your HTML and CSS code to your question for a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought linking my fiddle counted as that?  From now on i'll be sure to do that!

Comment: You are correct. I rushed through your question and didn't see any code, so I assumed you hadn't provided it. My mistake and I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use floats. You can keep it responsive with left and right absolute positions:

http://jsfiddle.net/ErAWn/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I am new to responsive design, but I like the idea of not using floats.  Are there any issues down the road with the absolute positioning?

Comment: Just remember that the parent container needs to be positioned as well. If not absolutely then it needs to have `position:relative` or else the absolutely positioned element will be positioned with respect to the WINDOW not the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Applying this style to the side column works in Safari, Chrome and FF even though does not seem to work in jsfiddle, plus floating is preserved if you need it:

```
.side_col {
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I had not yet tried it out of jsfiddle.  It seems to have some issues in ie8 and before.  I guess in the future I won't assume that jsfiddle works perfectly... rookie mistake...